# Jacoco converting coverage.ec to reports without coverage.em

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, emma

I was able to get the code coverage report by following the steps below,

1. Enable coverage on the build type you want (e.g. debug)

   `buildTypes {
         debug {
           testCoverageEnabled true
         }
   }`
2. Apply Jacoco plugin and set version

   `apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    jacoco {
        version "0.7.1.201405082137"
   }`
3. Run

   `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport`
4. All the tests in connectedAndroidTest are run and coverage report is generated based on them. I can find the coverage reports in

   `app/build/outputs/reports/coverage/{buildType}/index.html`

and a coverage.ec file in

`app/build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec`

But no jacoco.exec since I am running from Android Instrumentation instead of Robolectric test cases.

And when I run the instrumentation from ADB ( I guess this is still using Emma ) as follows, I get a coverage.ec file as follows,

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -e coverage true -e coverageFile /sdcard/coverage.ec com.sample.helloworld.test/.Runner
....
OK (4 tests)

Generated code coverage data to /sdcard/coverage.ec
```

But I am not able to convert the coverage.ec to report using emma since the coverage.em file is missing,

```
java -cp ~/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/lib/emma_device.jar emma report -r html -in \
coverage.em,myFile.ec,myapp_coverage1.ec -sp /path/to/myapp/src
```

Is there a way around this problem??

Answer (score 8):

Simply use the "coverage.ec" as the ".exec" file, it's worked for me

This is what Google did in Android Gradle Plugin source code.

public static final String FILE_COVERAGE_EC = "coverage.ec";

in SimpleTestCallable.java under com.android.builder.internal.testing package.

Comment: Wow, yes you can simply rename the file to `coverage.exec` and it becomes selectable in Android Studio (2.0) under `Show Coverage Data` and you get all your code nicely highlighted right in the editor window.

Comment: @NicolasGramlich I changed it to exec and opened it through Show Coverage Data - but it shows 0% for all the code

Comment: @UrielFrankel I met the same problem, so have you resolved it ?

Comment: yes. I have. i dived into the code of the jacoco and build a jar. and after a lot of twiking it works.

Comment: @UrielFrankel Care to share with us what you did?
A lot of people will be grateful for it, including me :)

Comment: It is a very long and painful and full of black magic answer. So hold on, and I will do it.

Comment: http://blog.houzz.com/post/158160064293/android-code-coverage-with-jacoco

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an article about the same scenario and my solution. [You can read it here](http://blog.houzz.com/post/158160064293/android-code-coverage-with-jacoco). For answering this specific question you should do the following steps: 
Change gradle to this:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco {
   toolVersion = '0.7.5.201505241946'
}
```

Second [download this jar](https://github.com/uriel-frankel/android-code-coverage/raw/master/hellojacoco/android-jacoco-the-missing.jar). Continue with the things you did until you have coverage.ec file. Then when you have it run:

```
java -jar android-jacoco-the-missing.jar -f /path/to/coverage.ec -p ./path/to/android/project
```

And thats it! The jar will generate a folder with the code coverage.

Another option is to use the coverage.ec with the Jenkins Jacoco plugin. But for that you need to have Jenkins set on.

Comment: Executing the jar always gives me `FileNotFoundException`. The file is there and I checked the path multiple times.

Comment: I am sure it is in the correct location. I checked it multiple times. Another thing I noticed is that the jar wants to sit in the project dir and get relative path to the file, which is not very flexible.

Comment: Run the jar without parameters and you will see the options you have

Comment: Any chances to have this jar genereting xml reports ?

Comment: If you are using Jenkins, there is a plugin for that.

Comment: I can;t even get an ec file because the class not found excpetion happens before that gets generated

Answer (score 1):

To get the coverage out of `coverage.ec` file just rename it to `coverage.exec` and the open it with "Show coverage data" option

"**Show coverage data**" can be found under "**Analyze**" option in Android Studio.

Verified this with Android Studio 3.3

Answer (score 0):

Remove . from following command its work for me

```
java -jar android-jacoco-the-missing.jar -f /path/to/coverage.ec -p /path/to/android/project
```