# Covert coverage.ec file to Jacoco report

Tags: android, code-coverage, jacoco, test-coverage

I am trying to get code coverage for my Android app, what I noticed is when the tests fail, the jacoco report does NOT get generated, only the coverage.ec gets generated.

Does anyone know how to covert coverage.ec file to jacoco report?

this didn't work for me: [Jacoco converting coverage.ec to reports without coverage.em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039751/jacoco-converting-coverage-ec-to-reports-without-coverage-em)

All the best!

Johnny