# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with test coverage and gradle plugin 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I'm trying to update my app to the new android gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha1. I've went through the migration guide at https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html and as far as I can tell everything is as it's suppose to be. I've tripled check this.

My project setup is quite simple I have a `lib2` that depends on `lib1`. Everything runs smoothly until code coverage comes into play. All tests in `lib1` run without a problem, but the tests in `lib2` that hit code from `lib1` throw the famous exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.Offline
```

All other tests from `lib2` run without a single problem.

I've tried every solution I found on the web. From forcing the version of jacoco for both libs. Using the one that comes packaged with the android plugin. Using the standalone jacoco plugin. Excluding the problematic classes from code coverage. Moving the tests to a separate module, which produces a greater amount of failures with the given exception. It seems that every time a library depends on another, this fails.

The weirdest part is that unpacking the jacoco agent reveals that the class is actually there - for both libs.

Has anyone come across the issue and has a solution? Thank you

Comment: What an annoying error. 8 hours trying to find a solution. Hope to find and post it here soon.

Comment: This is caused due to a bug on Jacoco version `0.7.6.201602180812`. Reference from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195754/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-jacoco-agent-rt-inter/45947840

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal\_14f7ee5/Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195754/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-jacoco-agent-rt-inter)